# git version 1.9.3 push fails

Tags: git, push

So, I have cloned this repository https://github.com/rdpeng/ProgrammingAssignment2

and made some changes and committed my changes locally, but I cannot push them to my remote repository!

Here is the output:

```
git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

fatal: remote error: 
  You can't push to git://github.com/mirjalil/ProgrammingAssignment2.git
  Use https://github.com/mirjalil/ProgrammingAssignment2.git
```

Here is more info on my git and repo:
git --version

```
1.9.3
```

git branch

```
* master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is stated right at the bottom.

```
fatal: remote error: 
  You can't push to git://github.com/mirjalil/ProgrammingAssignment2.git
  Use https://github.com/mirjalil/ProgrammingAssignment2.git
```

You have added your fork using `git://` URL, which only supports reading, not updating. To properly push to your form, you need to use an SSH URL, or an `http://` URL.

So you can run this to change the URL that your remote points at.

```
 git remote set-url <fork remote> https://github.com/mirjalil/ProgrammingAssignment2.git
```

Everything above the error message is entirely unrelated to the error and is just letting you know about upcoming changes for git 2 so that you don't get unexpected behavior if you eventually update.